# setInterval и задержки

Tags: javascript, setinterval

День добрый, Господа! При написании скрипта столкнулся с такой проблемой: я задал переменной значение, затем я подставил эту переменную в setInterval в задержку, однако при изменении этой переменной интервал между выполнениями функции не изменялся. Возник вопрос: можно ли вообще подставить переменную как значение задержки в setInterval.
Такой код есть на данный момент, передаю вам штурвал.

```js
setInterval(ggg, 1000);
var iter = 0;
var pulse = 90;
var time = 100;
setInterval(timer, 1000);
function ggg() {
 var aza = setInterval(ggg, 1000);
 setTimeout(ggg, 1000);
 clearInterval(aza);
 var aza = setInterval(ggg, 2000);
};
function pulsing() {
 heart.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
 setTimeout(back, 300);
  function back() {
   heart.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  };
};
function timer() {
 time--;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Kek</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kek.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
 <div id="heart" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
<script src="kek.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А Вы не забываете сбросить таймер?

Comment: Про какой именно таймер идёт речь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, переменную как значение задержки в setInterval подставить нельзя, вот почему:
setInterval выполняет код много раз ***через равные промежутки времени***, пока он не будет остановлен вызовом clearInterval. т.е. ***промежуток задается один раз*** (при вызове setInterval).

Для того, чтобы сделать так, как вы хотите - нужно каждый раз "уничтожать" setInterval и заново создавать его, с уже новым промежутком(который есть у вас в переменной).

PS. это можно сделать разными способами, как один из возможных - при помощи *Object.prototype.watch()* (учитывая его не поддержку:D, можно юзать - [полифилл](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583)).

```
var timerObj = { interval: 0, timerId: 0, func: my_function}; // объект для интервала

timerObj.watch('interval', function(prop, oldval, val) {
    // тут пересоздавать сам setInterval нужно:
    if(timerObj.timerId) clearTimeout(timerObj.timerId);
    timerObj.timerId = setInterval(this.func, val);
});

timerObj.interval = 1000; // запустили интервал

// много кода

timerObj.interval = 5000; // в любом месте меняет, он сам пересоздается)

// можно еще придумать методы для полной остановки и т.д.
```

PPS. как в комментариях верно подметили - лучше использовать *Object.defineProperty*, тогда код выглядел бы так(полифилл не нужен):

```
var timerObj = {timerId: 0, func: my_function}; // объект для интервала
Object.defineProperty(timerObj, 'interval', {
    set:function(val){
       if(timerObj.timerId) clearTimeout(timerObj.timerId);
       timerObj.timerId = setInterval(timerObj.func, val);
    }
});

timerObj.interval = 1000;

// много кода

timerObj.interval = 5000;
```

Answer (score 3):

Под переменной ты понимаешь: переменный период интервала. Период в `setInterval` статичен - прямо в вызове `setInterval` нельзя его сделать переменным. Но можно сделать переменный интервал времени другими способами.

Держи пример - каждый шаг таймера произвольный, от 0 до 1 сек:

```js
var someAction = function(){
 console.log(new Date());
 //clearTimeout на случай - чтобы при множественном запуске someAction вне, всё было ОК
 clearTimeout(someAction.timeout);
 someAction.timeout = setTimeout(someAction, Math.random()*1000);
};
someAction();
```

Comment: Нет смысла делать clearTimeout когда таймер уже сработал.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov есть, если в коде - someAction() вызывается несколько раз - я же комментарий добавил.. Это же "рекурсивный таймаут" - запустить несколько раз, будет работать одновременно несколько потоков - что обычно неконтроллируемо и является багом.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем мире слишком много магии. Для начала, вам следует осознать: любое выражение, которое вы напишите, будет вычислено сразу же, еще до того как кто-то воспользуется его значением.

Передача переменной в `setInterval` ничем не отличается от передачи константы.

Для того, чтобы изменить интервал выполнения - надо пересоздать таймер.

---

Вставлять вызов пересоздание таймера каждый раз когда надо изменить интервал - неправильно и нарушает принцип DRY ("не повторяйся!"). Поэтому лучше инкапсулировать таймер в объект:

```
function Timer (callback, interval) {
  this.callback = callback;
  this.timerId = null;
  this.setInterval(interval);
}
Timer.prototype.setInterval = function (interval) {
  if(this.timerId !== null) clearInterval(timerObj.timerId);
  this.timerId = setInterval(this.callback, val);
}

// ...

var timer = new Timer(some_function, 1000);

// ...

timer.setInterval(5000);
```