# Зачем используют setInterval(fn(),0);

Tags: javascript, многопоточность

Подскажите, где почитать про поточность JavaScript, желательно на русском?
Как я понял, что `setInterval(fn(),0);` - связана с темой потоков в JS?

Comment: `setInterval` связана лишь с выполнением некой функции с заданным временным интервалом.

Comment: `js` - однопоточный язык. А `setTimeout / setInterval` - это некое  отложенное выполнение. Где `setTimeout` - выполняется только один раз, через указанное время, а `setInterval` - выполняется каждый раз (постоянно), через указанное время.

Comment: Вот это, но если у вас нет опыта в js или значительного опыта в других языках, будет сложно: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Про многопоточность: js однопоточный by design. Есть возможность многопоточности через веб-воркеры, но надо понимтаь что это браузерное апи а не часть языка js. Видео сверху объясняет что собственно происходит при вызове вашего этого setInterval внутри

Comment: В этом коде выполняется функция fn() ещё ПЕРЕД выполнением setInterval, и смысл этого кода зависит от того, что fn вернёт. Возможно, смысла нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval()` - запускает выполнение функции не один раз, а регулярно повторяет её через указанный интервал времени. (Смысл тот же что и  `setTimeout()`, но разница все же есть)

#### Литература

[learn.javascript.ru - online на русском](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

[Про многопоточность на habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?target_type=posts&order_by=relevance&q=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+JavaScript&flow=)

Рекомендую ознакомиться с этим примером:

[setInterval и задержки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570971/setinterval-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8?rq=1)